# Check for balanced parentheses in an expression in log-space

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free, space-complexity, parsers

Given an expression (a word in the one-sided Dyck language), I want to write a program to examine whether the pairs and the orders of “{“,”}”,”(“,”)”,”[“,”]” are correct in the expression.  For example, the program should print true with begin-end pair of symbols indices for exp = “[()]{}{()()}” and false for exp = “[(])”.

The naive solution with a stack has O(n) time-complexity and O(n) space-complexity.  Can we solve this problem in O(log(n)) space-complexity?  In other words, can we parse Dyck languages in logarithmic space?

Comment: [LOGCFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOGCFL) contains NL, so my guess is that if your input tape is read-only, you can't do this in logarithmic space.

Comment: Do the different types of parentheses have to nest properly, which would give a [Dyck language](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19799/98), or can they appear independently of each other, which would make the language non-CFL?

Comment: Thanks. So your question is: Can we parse Dyck-languages in logarithmic space? (You may want to Google using these terms.)

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Lynch/jacm77.pdf)?

Comment: Do you require the time-complexity of the logarithmic space algorithm to still be linear? Or are you looking for a time-space tradeoff?

Answer (score 7):

The [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) on any fixed number of symbols can be recognised by a marking automaton, which is a two-way finite automaton that can mark a fixed number of input tape squares.
The automaton simply uses a different mark for each type of parenthesis.
Since a marking automaton is easily implemented by a Turing machine with a fixed number of logarithmic-sized regions of the worktape forming pointers into the input, Dyck languages can be parsed in logspace.

- R. W. Ritchie and F. N. Springsteel, *Language Recognition by Marking Automata*, Information and Control **20**, 313–330, 1972.
  doi:[10.1016/S0019-9958(72)90205-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(72)90205-7)